# Как получить ключ из массива js?

Tags: javascript

```
users[user.id] = currentUser;
users[39kddo] = 1;
```

Как получить ключ зная значение 1?

Comment: это же не массив, а объект. перебором (for in) можно. или сделать индекс, или сделать из этого модель с геттерами и сеттерами, которая сама будет делать индекс.

Comment: да - объект. можно простой пример?

Comment: в смысле ? 

    function searchInObj(obj,value) {
       for (var key in obj) {if (obj[key]===value) return key;}
       return false;
    }

*как вы программируете не зная основ синтаксиса ?* (это если что не стёб, я просто тоже так хочу уметь)

Answer (score 2):

```
function findKeyByValue(list, value) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(list) === '[object Array]') {
        return list.indexOf(value);
    } else if (list !== null && typeof list === 'object') {
        for (var key in list) {
            if (list.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (list[key] === value) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

```
var data = {
    'arr': [4, 5, 10, 'test', 2],
    'obj': {
        bar: 'data',
        foo: 'test'
    },
    'str': 'abcde',
    'num': 12345,
    'null': null
};

for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(findKeyByValue(data[key], 'test'));
    }
}

/**
 * 3
 * foo
 * null
 * null
 * null
 */
```

Comment: может тогда определять массив и использовать indexOf ?

Comment: Спасибо за это замечание. Доработал функцию.

Comment: Что-то не работает ваша функция: объект имеет структуру:
users = { '145': 'LGqjypOFpqIsRNbD5s-v', '151': 'U3f2iVtvAb2cY7Y75s-w' }

var data.to = 151;
var id = findKeyByValue(users, data.to);

Выдает null

Comment: @IOleg, что вы хотели сделать вот этой строкой?

    var data.to = 151

объявить переменную `to` в объекте `data`? что бы это значило?  

key (ключ) - это что до двоеточия, а после двоеточия - это value.  

    var datato = 'U3f2iVtvAb2cY7Y75s-w';
    var id = findKeyByValue(users, datato);
    // id == 151

Comment: Эта запись неправильная. Я хотел показать что на входе в функцию имеется объект users и переменная data.to со значением 151. Ключ которой не ищется

Comment: Получается, что местами ключ и значение поменять

Comment: Неправильно вопрос поставил, потом поменял местами ключ и значение.
Думаю такой вариант будет самым простым:

function findKeyByValue(list, value) {
    if (value in list) { return users[value]; }
    return false;
}

Comment: жесть...

    function findKeyByValue(list, value) {return list[value] || false;}